# Upper bound to the number of solutions of the following Diophantine Equation.

Tags: number-theory

The question is: Suppose that *p* is an odd prime. Obtain an upper bound to the number of solutions in terms of *p* for the number of solutions to $$y^p=x^2 +2.$$

I have found the integers that satisfy the equation $y^3=x^2 +2$ by firstly considering congruences modulo $4$ to prove that *y* is odd, that $x+\sqrt{-2}$ and $x-\sqrt{-2}$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and that $x+\sqrt{-2}$ is equal to the cube of a member of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. So the solutions are:

$$(x,y)=(5,3),(-5,3).$$

I'm unsure how to modify my solution to $y^3=x^2 +2$ to find an upper bound without repeating the whole proof. But considering the question is only worth $4$ marks I assume there must be a quick way to find the solution. Any advice would be appreciated. I am aware that the answer is perhaps $p-1$.